# How to get difference between numbers with same dates in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table like this:

```
PK     COUNTER     READ     READ_DATE
1         1         1       1/1/2017
2         1         2       1/1/2017
3         1         3       1/12/2018
4         4         4       1/12/2018
```

In `READ_DATE` column 2 same dates with different numbers.

If user select 2 dates like `Start_Date(1/1/2017)` and `End_date(1/12/2018)`.

I want get difference between in 2 numbers from `READ` column with same dates.

How to write sql query in oracle?

Comment: Which result do you expect to get from data you posted?

Comment: different from 'READ' column in same dates

Comment: Post an exact answer you would like to get for the sample data you've shown. Your question is also a bin unclear on the significance of `start_date` and `end_date`. The names suggest you may want to treat it as a range and capture everything in between. You're giving two dates, each of those in your sample data has 2 entries, so we have 4 entries, but you're saying to calculate a difference between 2 numbers. Which two of the four?

Comment: Add a sample output

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the absolute difference, you may try a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT
    READ_DATE,
    MAX(READ) - MIN(READ) AS diff
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    READ_DATE;
```